# converting binary to utf-8 in python

Tags: python, string, utf-8, binary, converters

I have a binary like this:
    `1101100110000110110110011000001011011000101001111101100010101000`

and  I want to convert it to utf-8.
how can I do this in python?

Comment: What encoding is the binary string in? ASCII? Or you mean the bytes are a utf-8-encoded string and you want to get a unicode string in python?

Comment: What do you mean with "convert it to utf-8"? Create the characters from the binary octets?

Comment: the binary string is in utf-8 and yes, I want to get a unicode string in python.

Comment: I think we're not understanding precisely what sort of file you have. Could you run `hd` or `od` or a similar hex-dump utility and copy-paste the first few lines?

Comment: it's not a file. I just have a text in persian and I convert it to binary, now I want to convert it back to the text.

Comment: Tell us more. For example, how did you convert it to binary?

Comment: This: https://sites.google.com/site/nathanlexwww/tools/utf8-convert

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Cleaner version:

```
>>> test_string = '1101100110000110110110011000001011011000101001111101100010101000'
>>> print ('%x' % int(test_string, 2)).decode('hex').decode('utf-8')
نقاب
```

Inverse (from @Robᵩ's comment):

```
>>> '{:b}'.format(int(u'نقاب'.encode('utf-8').encode('hex'), 16))
1: '1101100110000110110110011000001011011000101001111101100010101000'
```

Comment: but it doesn't work properly. it shows something else, not the first text I just converted to binary

Comment: worked, thank you. I think I should move the check to this answer. It's really simpler

Comment: And the inverse would be: `s=u'نقاب'; print '{:b}'.format(int(s.encode('utf-8').encode('hex'), 16))`

Comment: @Robᵩ added to the answer with minor edit (I think in this case `.encode('utf-8')` in unnecessary).

Comment: Or maybe I am wrong. Direct version worked for me without `.decode('utf-8')` as well. Any idea why that could happen?

Comment: @Igonato - Dunno. With what you have in the answer, I get UnicodeEncodeError.

Comment: I receive the text from user and put it in a variable called s. but /'{:b}'.format(int(s.encode('utf-8').encode('hex'), 16))/ won't work. how can I change s to unicode type?

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Works for me, I don't know how to help you. @Robᵩ can you test the string from previous comment?

Comment: @Aidin.T if you testing it with a file ensure that it saved in utf-8 encoding and there is `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` line at the top.

Comment: Did you execute this code? /s = "سلام" ; '{:b}'.format(int(s.encode('utf-8').encode('hex'), 16))/

Comment: Yes, I did. Works fine for me.

Comment: @Igonato no, it's not a file

Comment: Weird indeed. I am running out of ideas. Try to put it in file, save it with proper encoding and then run it from cmd like `python my_file.py`. Don't forget `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Comment: Note that `s = "سلام"` and `s = u"سلام"` give different results. The former fails, the latter works. But let's stop solving the new problem. @Aidin.T, if you have a problem with *encoding*, please open a new question.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the idea I have is:
 1. Split the string into octets
 2. Convert the octet to hexadecimal using `int` and later `chr`
 3. Join them and decode the utf-8 string into Unicode

This code works for me, but I'm not sure what does it print because I don't have utf-8 in my console (Windows :P ).

```
s = '1101100110000110110110011000001011011000101001111101100010101000'
u = "".join([chr(int(x,2)) for x in [s[i:i+8] 
                           for i in range(0,len(s), 8)
                           ]
            ])
d = u.decode('utf-8')
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hmmm, I'm somewhat suspicious of `unichr`. Because OP says his binary is already utf-8. utf-8 has variable character length, so I just used `chr` to join the raw bytes in a string and decode them later into Unicode.

Comment: @JoranBeasley - I disagree, assuming Python2. In that step he is collecting bytes, not characters. Only after he has the utf-8-encoded byte string does he want to convert.

Comment: @Robᵩ: That's my point. Nice answer, love the `split('........')`. I think is basically the same idea as mine. +1

Comment: +1 - This is the same technique as mine (so obviously I approve), plus you explained yours. Questioner should move the check to this better answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> s='1101100110000110110110011000001011011000101001111101100010101000'
>>> print (''.join([chr(int(x,2)) for x in re.split('(........)', s) if x ])).decode('utf-8')
نقاب
>>>
```

Or, the inverse:

```
>>> s=u'نقاب'
>>> ''.join(['{:b}'.format(ord(x)) for x in s.encode('utf-8')])
'1101100110000110110110011000001011011000101001111101100010101000'
>>>
```

Comment: there is another question, how can I convert my text to binary by python? I mean the inverse form of my question

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
def bin2text(s): return "".join([chr(int(s[i:i+8],2)) for i in xrange(0,len(s),8)])


>>> print bin2text("01110100011001010111001101110100")
>>> test
```

Comment: for my text it returns this: '\xd9\x86\xd9\x82\xd8\xa7\xd8\xa8', how can I get it in the right way of showing?

Comment: You want `unichr()`, not just `chr()`. http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unichr