# Converting Unicode to Binary

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8

I am trying to convert Arabic text to `utf8` encoded bytes then to binary by using [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19255832/converting-binary-to-utf-8-in-python).

First, I used the code as it is in the example:

```
'{:b}'.format(int(u'سلام'.encode('utf-8').encode('hex'), 16))
```

But I got this error:

```
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Also I removed `.encode('hex')` but still gives the same error.

Is there any way to convert `utf8` codes to binary and vise versa?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815592/convert-bytes-to-bits-in-python?

Comment: @pstatix and how can I do the inverse ? from bits to utf8

Comment: you don't encode utf8 to something, it is already encoded in a sequence of bytes, you can only decode it to text (text was originally encoded to utf-8, that was your beginning point)

Comment: to do the inverse of encode, you decode.

Comment: Quick question, why do you want to get this to binary in the first place. If this is just about encoding then there are significantly better ways of doing it such as the [`base64`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html) modules.

Comment: If you do want binary, would recommend looking at a library such as [bitstring](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitstring/3.1.3) to do it for you.

Comment: @SCB I want to use the binary for security purposes needs in my program. So I need them in binary first then use this binary string alone,  and when I received binary again I want to back it in utf8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
>>> ''.join('{:08b}'.format(b) for b in 'سلام'.encode('utf8'))
'1101100010110011110110011000010011011000101001111101100110000101'
```

This iterates over the encoded `bytes` object, where you get an integer in the range 0..255 for each iteration.
Then the integer is formatted in binary notation with zero padding up to 8 digits.
Then glue everything together with `str.join()`.

For the inverse, the approach given in an answer from the question you linked to can be adapted to Python 3 as follows (`s` is the output of the above example, ie. a `str` of 0s and 1s):

```
>>> import re
>>> bytes(int(b, 2) for b in re.split('(........)', s) if b).decode('utf8')
'سلام'
```